# onPrepareOptionsMenu is called twice on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-optionsmenu

A skeleton app that extends `Activity` (not `AppCompatActivity`) seems to call `onPrepareOptionsMenu` twice on screen rotation.

(I read the question: [Fragment is called twice on screen rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42523548/3501958). However, I'm not using a `Fragment` here.)

Is this a bug or a regular behavior? Are there any solution to avoid this?

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("onCreate", "called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new View(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d("onPrepareOptionsMenu", "called " + ++count);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (Module:app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rotationtest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

**logcat (after rotation):**

```
03-28 23:58:40.134 3358-3358/com.rotationtest D/onCreate: called
03-28 23:58:40.141 3358-3358/com.rotationtest D/onPrepareOptionsMenu: called 1
03-28 23:58:40.141 3358-3358/com.rotationtest D/onPrepareOptionsMenu: called 2
```

Answer (score 0):

any reason you need to use extends Activity?
I imagine extending AppCombatActivity prevents this bug.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If urgently I need to solve this, I would use `AppCompatActivity`. Now I just wonder if this is a bug or not. So, I also reported to the AOSP (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=270034).